# Formatting user JSON with and without premium features

Tags: json, api

I'm trying to figure out the best way to format a user's JSON returned by an API. Here's the basic object:

```
user {
  name: 'john',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  signed_up: '12-12-2012',
}
```

How do I add the user's premium plan features to the JSON? The user can either be `Free`or be a `Pro` or `Business`. The problem is that both `Pro` and `Business` include an object with further info regarding the plan while the `Free` plan includes nothing.

Is it ok to return a string for the plan in case it's `Free` and an object in case it's paid? Or should I avoid using different return types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the following format:

Free users:

```
response: {
  user: {
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    signed_up: '12-12-2012',
    plan: {
      name: 'Free',
      billing_period: null
      price: null
    }
  },
}
```

Premium users:

```
response: {
  user: {
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    signed_up: '12-12-2012',
    plan: {
      name: 'Premium',
      billing_period: 12
      price: 299
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format your response as shown below. If the premium is `Pro` or `Business` then the `furtherInfo` object will have the futher information, else if it is `Free`, then the `response` should not have the further information.

```
response: {
  user: {
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    signed_up: '12-12-2012',
    premium: 'Pro'
  },
  furtherInfo: {
    attribute1: 'value1',
    ....
    attributeN: 'valueN'
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
response: {
  user: {
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    signed_up: '12-12-2012',
    premium: 'Free'
  }
}
```